# Calculating the size of Array::pack format string

Tags: ruby

How do you calculate the length of the string that would be returned by Array::pack?  Is there something like Python's calcsize?

Answer (score 1):

array.pack("").count I would say. Not really the fastest method, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

By making an interpreter complying to the specifications found in [Array::pack](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002245).

Or, reusing the existing implementation to count the number of characters instead of appending them to a string.